# How do I create a new logical partition from unallocated space?

Tags: partitioning

I bought a new hard drive and installed Windows followed by Ubuntu 11.04 on it.  In the screenshot below, Windows System, C:, swap are Primary partitions.  I then put / and /home in an extended partition.  I left about 150GB, which is highlighted, because I wanted to make it a D: later.

Windows will not let me format that volume, since I have already have 4 partitions.
Ubuntu Disk Utility is not recognizing it and I cannot create a partition from that allocated space either.

Is it possible to take that unallocated space, and put it under the "Extended partition" without extending any existing partitions?  My aim is to have a partition formatted in NTFS/FAT32 that both Ubuntu and Windows can use.

I will reformat and reinstall if required but would like to know if there is a quicker way first.

[image: Disk Utility]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resize the expended partition so it occupies all the space which is currently unallocated and then create an NTFS partition inside the extended partition. Since only the end of the extended partition need to be moved, the existing partitions inside it can be kept and also the operation will be quite fast.

I second the suggestion of brunopereira81 to use `gparted` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use gparted for that (install it with `sudo apt-get install gparted` or look for `gparted` at the `USC`).

Select the unallocated disk space, right click on it and select `New`

[image]