# Dual booting Ubuntu 11.10 and Fedora 16 [ problem partitioning ]

Tags: partitioning, dual-boot, fedora

I have 320 gb hard drive. It already has a drive each for Ubuntu installation, Home, an NTFS drive and swap partition.

With the space that is left over, I want to try Fedora 16 too as it has some good reviews. However, everytime I try to do so, there is this message that says we can not have MORE THAN 4 PRIMARY PARTITION. **How do I bypass this without losing data ?**

Also, is it possible to use the same Home partition for both OS ?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! It would be appreciated if you posted separate questions instead of combining all your questions in one. About the primary partition issue, you need to use Logical or Extended partitions to have more than 4 partitions. To learn how to do that take a look at this question - [How do I create a new logical partition from unallocated space?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73467/how-do-i-create-a-new-logical-partition-from-unallocated-space).

Comment: I agree with nitstorm. The last question has been answered several times on AU though so it is more than likely to be closed if you make it a seperate one... the answer is yes by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a maximum of 4 [primary partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Primary_partition) on 1 hard disc (where only 1 can be active at the same time). You need to use logical partitions inside an [extended partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Extended_partition).

Maybe an image is easier:

[image]

`hda` is the harddisc.
`hda1`, `hda2`, `hda3` are primary and `hda3` holds an extended partition with logical partitions `hda5`, `hda6`, `hda7` and `hda8`.

Regarding:

> How do I bypass this without losing data ?

Make a backup of anything important before you do anything else. Put in on a USB stick, CD or DVD or BD depending on the hardware you have and the size of the data.

Comment: Apologies for not going by the etiquette. I will definitely take care from the next time. Thanks a ton for replying my queries promptly.

Comment: No need to apologize. We had to learn it ourself too ;)