# How to make a new partition from an empty volume?

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I have a 931 GB hard drive with 3 logical volumes. One for ubuntu(100 GB), One is for swap(4 GB), and the third one(891 GB) is empty as shown in the pics. The question is, how can I make a new partition from the empty logical volume (named data)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/73467/how-do-i-create-a-new-logical-partition-from-unallocated-space?rq=1

Comment: the 'data' partition isn't unallocated in my case.

Comment: can you click on one third partition? and then select _partition_ > _New_ ?

Comment: I do not see anything empty. Your disk has 3 partitions. You can remove sda3 and create a new one if you like.

Comment: sda3 has ubuntu installed on the 'root' volume. I want to make a new partition from data volume, which is a part of sda3 along with 'root'. So I can't remove sda3. By empty I meant I haven't stored anything on the 'data' volume.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to downsize sda3,and then create a new partition in the resulted empty space. You can't create a partition from another partition. LVM (Logical Volume Management) is only necessary when dealing with multiple harddisks. If you have just one harddisk (Disks app says so) LVM is quite useless.

Comment: I've deleted the 'data' volume. Now sda3 has 830 GB free space. But I can't resize the partition with gparted. it says:   ' /dev/sda3 : cannot resize to 28116 extents as later ones are allocated'

Comment: Select sda3, right-click on it and choose Delete. Press the 'Apply Changes' button (the green check sign). Right-click on the empty space and choose 'Create partition'. Set the partition size and press 'Apply changes' button again.

Comment: is it safe to delete sda3? cos' I have ubuntu installed on it.

Comment: OK, don't delete it, choose Resize instead of Delete from the same menu. Make it smaller, Apply Changes, then click on the empty space and create a new partition.

Comment: It doesn't work. Gparted gives the error I mentioned above.

Comment: Read this on how to remove an LVM partition: http://askubuntu.com/questions/217571/cant-format-delete-locked-partition-from-gparted.